# How to properly configure an stm32 with lmt86?

Tags: stm32, sensors, stm32f4, stm32cubeide, stm32f3

I'm implementing an stm32 which reads data from an LTM86 sensor and transmits the converted temperature in a CAN bus.
My problem is related to the ADC configuration because the voltage value provided by the ADC is different from that measured on the pin with a voltmeter. As a consequence, the converted temperature will be wrong.

I tried this ADC setup:

[image: ADC setting]

Comment: Is different? What does it mean? Is it 1V or 0.01V difference?

Comment: my temperature is 18°C which corresponds to 1907 mV (simply by looking the look up table), but the ADC gives me 2300 mV which corresponds to -18°C.